# How did Skynet obtain human skin and blood to build infiltrating Terminators?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

When the Terminator in *The Terminator* damaged itself it cut the eye tissue revealing the robotic eye and put the human eye cover in a tray. In Terminator 2 when John, Sarah and Terminator were at the Dyson's House the Terminator cuts its human flesh off its arm and blood oozes out.

How did Skynet get human tissue and blood to create T-800 infiltrators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's made clear in the *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* episode "The Turk" that Terminator skin can be grown, and very quickly.  A skinless Cromartie invaded the home of a molecular biologist and wrote the skin growth formulas and process on a wall.

[image: skin formula]

Some exotic chemistry was involved and twenty units of human blood were needed to bootstrap the process, but after that the skin and blood regenerate.  Cromartie stole the blood from a hospital, but **draining two or three human adults would yield enough blood to start the process.**

Upon realizing the process could work, dollar signs danced in front of the biologist's eyes and he agreed to  prepare the solution, into which Cromartie then immersed his naked endoskeleton.

[image: bathtub, T-888, scientist]

Hours later the rough outline of a human form emerged from the biologist's bathtub.

[image: emergence]

Interestingly, while the skin could be grown and attached to the endoskeleton in a relatively simple fashion, life-like eyes could not be so easily obtained.

[image: red eyes]

So Cromartie killed the scientist and harvested his eyes.

Comment: TSSC is a canon nightmare.

Answer (score 7):

**It's a [bit complicated](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Living_tissue).**

The *rumour* among the human rebels in Terminator: Salvation is that the Terminator's skin is taken from living humans. This is backed up by the fact that we see an industrial-scale dissection chamber (with multiple beds) later in the film, however these appear disused which would lend weight to the theory that Skynet has developed the ability to grow skin artificially:

> “I’ve heard what they do with prisoners. I heard the machines tear
>   your skin off your body while you’re still alive, slide it over a
>   metal skeleton so you can’t tell who’s human and who’s a machine.” - <sub><sup>[Terminator Salvation: The Official Movie Novelization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848560850)</sup></sub>

Moving down the canon scale, we see the "*Cyborg Tissue Generator*" in the Teaser Trailer for T2

and in the comic serials, it's made abundantly clear that the skin is grown directly onto the Terminators in "*tissue incubators*"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Skynet central hub located in San Francisco in Terminator Salvation has a large facility built for the development of the T800 which is the first model with Human skin,hair, teeth, ect. This is where captured humans are being experimented upon to gain knowledge for that purpose.

The human prisoners in Salvation are not a work force like Skynet  used them for in other scenarios. In the movie the area where the prisoners are offloaded is remarkably similar in design to a Nazi Concentration camp, rail lines and all. The prisoners are simply thrown in large metal containment boxes, they are very tightly packed in and are given nothing that would keep them alive, like you would give to a slave workforce.

In the scene where John Conner is searching for Kyle Reese in Skynet Central Command, he runs past several laboratories and medical facilities with operating tables and medical equipment. It's clear that the T800 human parts including skin,muscle, ability to sweat, a blood system, and even bad breath were developed in these facilities.

It all began with Dr. Serena Kogan in the early 2000's, a geneticist employed by Cyberdine systems and later a hybrid human collaborator working with Skynet to create cyborgs like Marcus that were the first stage infiltration units leading to the T800. When Marcus speaks directly with Skynet it scans his memories and on a screen it uses Dr. Kogan's Image because it thinks he will find her image less distressing than any other.